# mysql query inner join took 40 to 45 sec

Tags: mysql, performance

```
SELECT  a.gid, a.qid,
        SUM(a.result = 1) first_attempt_correct,
        SUM(a.result = 0) first_attempt_incorrect
        FROM maf_game_stats a
                LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT USERID, gid, QID, MIN(ACCESSTIME) min_date
                    FROM maf_game_stats
                    GROUP BY USERID, gid, qid
                )  b ON a.USERID = b.USERID AND
                    a.gid = b.gid AND
                    a.qid = b.qid AND
                    a.ACCESSTIME = b.min_date
        WHERE   a.gid ='2'
        AND a.ACCESSTIME >= '2014-09-01' AND a.ACCESSTIME < '2014-09-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        GROUP BY a.gid, a.qid
```

Above given query execution time 40 to 50 sec how can i break thses query

Comment: Or how to rewrite i already used indexing but no use..?

Comment: There is no way to index the left join derived table im not sure why you dont just join on the actual table and add some group bys ?

Comment: At minimum, update your question with an explain statement and table definitions.

Comment: please read [MY POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on how to ask a good question. we have no idea what you want to do or what your goal is.

Comment: Guessing, it sounds like you are dissatisfied with your query execution time. It may be possible to help you, but not unless you provide more information. Please show your table definition including the indexes you have in place. Please tell us how many rows are in your table, and in the result set. Please consider reading about compound covering indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Solution is below :

```
SELECT  a.gid, a.qid,
        SUM(a.result = 1) first_attempt_correct,
        SUM(a.result = 0) first_attempt_incorrect
        FROM maf_game_stats a
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT USERID, gid, QID, MIN(ACCESSTIME) min_date
                    FROM maf_game_stats
                    WHERE   gid ='2' 
                    AND ACCESSTIME >= '2014-09-01' AND ACCESSTIME < '2014-09-12' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                    GROUP BY USERID, gid, qid
                )  b ON a.USERID = b.USERID AND
                    a.gid = b.gid AND
                    a.qid = b.qid AND
                    a.ACCESSTIME = b.min_date
        WHERE   a.gid ='2'
        AND a.ACCESSTIME >= '2014-09-01' AND a.ACCESSTIME < '2014-09-12' + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        GROUP BY a.gid, a.qid
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

WHERE gid ='2'

to your inner left-join query.  Without it, you are querying for ALL "gid" values.  So, since your outer query only cares about "gid=2", who cares if you have "gid= 1, 3, 2903, or even 389433" in the inner result set.  Have that the same and it should be instantaneous.

Additionally, you may need to apply your date criteria to the inner query, but not sure exactly what you are trying to get out of it.

Comment: gid means game id, its maximum containing numbers 1 to 15 only.

Comment: @Vasanth, what was the final time on the revised query with the WHERE clause.  You mentioned 8-10 for Gordon's answer, yet marked my solution as the one that worked... more curious, and also good feedback in future when running with slow queries and what works and the final performance could help others see measurable differences in techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this using `not exists` and then adding some indexes.  The query is:

```
SELECT  gs.gid, gs.qid,
        SUM(gs.result = 1) first_attempt_correct,
        SUM(gs.result = 0) first_attempt_incorrect
FROM maf_game_stats gs
WHERE gs.gid ='2' AND
      gs.ACCESSTIME >= '2014-09-01' AND gs.ACCESSTIME < '2014-09-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM maf_game_stats gs2
                  WHERE gs2.gid = gs.gid and gs2.qid = gs.qid and gs2.AccessTime > gs2.AccessTime
                 )
GROUP BY gs.gid, gs.qid;
```

The indexes are:  `maf_game_starts(gid, accesstime, qid, result)` and `maf_game_stats(gid, qid, AccessTime)`.

Comment: it working nice it took aroung 8 - 10 sec execution time. thanks loot now i am checking with different ways.;)

Comment: execution time increased. but query attempt result correct,incorrect not fair.